# Backspace key not working in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and my <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key isn't working any more in any application.

I think it's unlikely to be a hardware problem because on the same day, before uninstalling a different operating system (non-Ubuntu), it still worked.

When I try adding Backspace to the Keyboard shortcuts, it automatically becomes "disabled".

I'm afraid I currently don't have any other keyboards I can try on my laptop. I have tried resetting the Keyboard under Settings.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
```

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967234 0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 500463, (693,296), root:(788,381),
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 26, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  63  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

ClientMessage event, serial 28, synthetic YES, window 0x3400001,
    message_type 0x136 (WM_PROTOCOLS), format 32, message 0x134 (WM_DELETE_WINDOW)
```

Comment: In all applications or just in your browser?

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? Do your results change if you go to Settings->Devices->Keyboard and click Reset All? Please [edit] the requested information into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Being unable to assign the Backspace key to any window manager keyboard shortcuts is normal. You're not supposed to do that because the key is meant for text editing normally and thus it's treated as a way to delete the current shortcut key assignment. Can you please run `xev -event keyboard`, focus the appearing application window, press the backspace key a few times, close the application and add its output to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I have edited the comment with the results.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry to bother but if you could help please. Thanks!